# need php code to obtain list of files stored on the server

Tags: php, ajax

How to display the list of files stored in the folder on the server using php and making a call to that php page using ajax so as to display the list of files to the user on the client machine?

Comment: this is not a code factory. please search this site and your favorite search engine, and post here when you have specific questions/things you're blocked on.

Comment: A good starting point is : http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Comment: [Embrace the non-googlers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers), [Ban LMGTFY Links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links)

Comment: @Jaref Farrish I'm not sure those apply to this question. If sumeeta asked for a PHP function to `explode` a string into an array I might agree with you. But he's is asking for a pre-packaged solution. Not *how* he should approach it or the technical challenges surrounding such a solution.. just the solution. However, this could qualify as a 'software algorithm' question as defined in the FAQ. Now you've got me second-guessing myself :p

Answer (score 1):

A very simple example:

http://jfcoder.com/test/showfilesget.php

**showfiles.php**

```
<?php 

// open this directory 
$dir = opendir("files");

// get each entry
while($file = readdir($dir)) {
    if (substr($file, 0, 1) != '.') {
        print "$file\n";
    }
}

// close directory
closedir($dir);

?>
```

**showfilesget.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loadfiles').click(function(){
        $.get('http://jfcoder.com/test/showfiles.php', function(data) {
            $('#files').html(data);
        });
    });
});

</script>

<h1>Loaded Files</h1>
<pre id="files"></pre>
<p><span class="link" id="loadfiles">Load files content</span></p>
```